# How to project data onto independent components using FastICA in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, signal-processing

I'm having a question regarding ICA ,it maybe a little basic but I'm new to it. I'm using [FastICA MATLAB toolbox](http://research.ics.aalto.fi/ica/fastica/)

I'm using it as :

```
[icasig] = fastica(train_data);
```

Where `train_data` is of size `[192x23]`.

What I understand is : `icasig` is supposed to be the independent components, so I was expecting that the size of it would be `23x23` ,the dimension number, like `PCA` output. Instead the size is `22x192`, where the dimensions are reduced to 22.
I don't understand what this represents.

So, my question is: does `icasig` represent the ICs? Then, if this is the case, how to use it to project the original data on the ICs?

If `icasig` represents the projection of original data on the ICs, how can I extract the ICs themselves to be used in another projection of the testdata?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The full `fastica.m` output is:

```
[icasig, A, W] = fastica(X); % outputs the estimated separating
matrix W and the corresponding mixing matrix A.
```

For a given data matrix `X` (assume `X` is a d x N matrix, i.e. each row is an observation), think about the following relationships that correspond to the output of `[Y, A, W] = fastica(X).`

**Unmixing**: `Y = W*X % X is separated on independent 'sources' Y`

`W` is a k x d matrix (k<=d) that separates the sources or independent components from the mixtures in X (d x N) and stores them in Y (k x N). If k is smaller than d, the resulting representation is of reduced dimensionality.

**Mixing**: `X = A*Y % Y sources are combined through the mixing matrix A`

`A` is an d x k matrix that mixes k components (k<=d) stored in matrix `Y` which is k x N (for N observations). *A stores the independent components extracted from X, i.e. d-dimensional vectors, k number in total*. Moreover `Y` stores the sources or *the projections of X on the independent components*.

From the output of `fastica` check the values of the following norms (the smaller the norms, the more accurate the separation of the ICA algorithm):

```
norm(W*X - Y)
norm(X - A*Y)
norm(pinv(A) - W)
norm(pinv(W) - A)
```

**Regarding the OP questions:**

- `icasig` represents the sources responsible of the data or the *projection* of the input data on the ICs estimated from `train_data`. In this case there are k ICs discovered, so 192 points are represented by their k values.
- The ICs are given by the vectors in the columns of A.
- `icasig` already gives you the projection of the original data on the ICs.
- You can use the separating matrix W (close to the pseudo-inverse of W) to project a new set of points `Xn` by `Yn = W*Xn`.

**Example:**

```
% Generate data (N=1000) from distribution
X = gendata(1000);

% Estimate ICs and projections of X  
[Y, A, W] = fastica(X, 'approach', 'defl');    

% New points from the same distribution  
Xn = gendata(50);

% Project new point on ICA estimated independent components  
Yn = W*Xn;
```

[image]

(Replace `gendata` with your own data generating function. For the plot I used the bimodal set, where the mixing is rotation in 2D, from J. Shlens, [A Tutorial on Independent Component Analysis](http://arxiv.org/abs/1404.2986))